# A simple scons example, I need guidance

Tags: scons

I created a simple hierarchial C++ project to help me learn the use of scons as I want to get away from cmake and qmake. I have registered it in a github repository at https://github.com/pleopard777/SConsEx . This project is organized into two primary subdirs; packages contains two libraries and testing contains two apps. The packages dir needs to be built first and when complete the testing dir needs to be built. Under the packages library the core library must be compiled first and the numerics library second. The numerics library depends on the core library. Under the testing dir the core_tests app depends on the core library and the numerics_tests app depends on core and numerics.

I am struggling with what seems to be limited documentation and examples for scons so I am posting this here in search of some guidance. Here are some of the initial problems I am having, any guidance will be greatly appreciated:

---

1) [Edit/FIXED]

---

2) In the packages/numerics/ dir the source files depend on the core library. The file numerics_config.h requires the file ../core/core_config.h however when building that core file cannot be found. The following SConstruct lines don't help:
[code]

```
include = '../../packages'
env = Environment(CPPPATH=include)
```

[/code]
Again, this is just a start to the project and I am using it to learn scons. Any guidance will be appreciated ... I'm sure I will be asking lots more questions as this project progresses.

Thanks!
P

Comment: Did you read the Users Guide and the Manpage? Also check the wiki on github. There's quite a bit of documentation.

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow is a wrong place for "guide me" requests. We want every question post to contain a **specific problem**, which resolution can be described in an *answer post*. Question posts which contains several (and separate) problems are not welcomed here. The same is about [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in pull request to your repo.
Note you had some c++ issues as well. I've fixed them too.

See:
https://github.com/pleopard777/SConsEx/pull/1

(Please don't delete your repo so others can find the solution as well)